# error when using catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros, uwsim, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use command catkin_make_isolated in the terminal, error is shown below:

```
    CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:111 (FILE):
      file INSTALL cannot set permissions on
      "/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/install_isolated/lib/libuwsim.so"
make: *** [install] Error 1
<== Failed to process package 'uwsim': 
  Command '/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/install_isolated/env.sh make install' returned non-zero exit status 2
Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/build_isolated/uwsim && /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/install_isolated/env.sh make install
Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237112/error-when-using-catkin_make_isolated/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the user your using have a write access at `/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/` and subsequent folders?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2021-03-09**:
PLZ, tell me how to give the user access to the folder!!! Thanks

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-03-12**:
@rayane Please ask somewhere else because 1) That's not related to ROS at all 2) There can be a number of different  ways to do so depending on your particular situation.